# Como marco en phpmyadmin NULL y NOTNULL

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Yo no se como marcar notnull, ni tampoco null, ademas soy nuevo y no tengo idea de para que sirven estas opciones, alguien me puede explicar! Muchas gracias

-Las tres primeras deberian ser not null
-las demas null.

Comment: que has investigado? por favor lee [ask]

Comment: recuerda SO no sustituye a Google [null y not null](http://sql.11sql.com/sql-not-null.htm)

Comment: y aqui el otro enlace [null y not null en phpmyadmin](https://disenowebakus.net/crear-una-base-de-datos-phpmyadmin-mysql-php.php)

Comment: Muchas gracias! colega!

Answer (score 1):

Null y Not null sirven para indicar que estos campos no pueden quedar vacíos al momentos de hacer un registro, por ejemplo si dices que id y nombre son not null, si quieres hacer un registro y pasas los datos vacíos te mandara un error MySql.

Como los activas, sencillo clic en Cambiar (tiene un lápiz alado) y te mandara a otra pagina y buscas un checkbox que diga Nulo y lo marcas.

la otra manera es con un query pero es mas larga.

Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias colega!